# Check image dimension before upload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to check an images width and height before i upload it to the server.

```
var file = _("fileupload").files[0];
    current_format = file.type;
    current_file = file;
    extension = file.name.substring(file.name.indexOf('.'), file.name.length);

if (file) {
    var img;
    img = new Image(file);
    img.onload = function() {
        alert(this.width + " " + this.height);
    };
    img.onerror = function() {
        alert( "not a valid file: " + file.type);
    };
}
```

I found the code here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4N6D9/1/)

Here it works perfectly, but for some reason when i implement it to my project and debug it, i can see it skips over the onload and onerror functions.

Comment: Did you try putting an `else` block on `if (file)` to see whether it's getting to the lines that run `img.onload = ` etc.?  Or maybe just stepping through with a debugger?

Comment: @Kev I have debugget it and it steps inside the `if`. The problem is when it gets to `img.onload` its value is null, and therefor skips over it

Comment: The `img.onload` and `img.onerror` are performed asynchronously.  Maybe you should add your code so people can help you better. It's impossible to know what is "my project" when you provide no code...

Comment: Sorry, what value is null?  Before or after?